# Reading and writing to java KeyStore

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, jca

My app needs **only** to read private keys(with associated public cert), no writing to KeyStore, no password changing, **no changes at all** - just reading.
Does anybody know for sure that for reading I can use this code:

```
///doing some actions
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("foo", "bar");
store.load(iaminputstream, iampwd); // I'M JUST LOADING, I'M NOT GONNA STORE IT!
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) store.getKey(iamalias, iamkeypass);
Certificate cert = store.getCertificate(iamalias);
///contnuing some actions
```

instead of this:

```
///doing some actions
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("foo", "bar");

try{
    store.load(iaminputstream, iampwd); //I'VE LOADED

    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) store.getKey(iamalias, iamkeypass);
    Certificate cert = store.getCertificate(iamalias);

} finally {
    store.store(iamoutputstream, iampassword); //AND I'VE SAVED!
}
///contnuing some actions
```

Prove link is highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you actually run the code and found any issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to save it of course. Just don't forget to handle exceptions.
Take a look at [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) - there is nothing about required saving after load() call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not storing anything, you don't have to call `store.store()`

But do remember to close the inputstream and handle exceptions.